# Project site mistakenly deleted - how to restore?

Tags: project-server

An admin user accidentally deleted a Project Server project site, is there any way to restore the project site?  I've checked the site collection recycle bin and other recycle bins and haven't found a trace of the project site.

For now, I've created a new project site with a backup of that particular project schedule, but it's missing all of the SharePoint list items, such as Risks and Issues, that were previously associated with the project.

I have tried Administrative Restore for that particular project, but it's throwing an error - `ProjectNameAlreadyExists`.  I'm not sure if that feature would restore the project site anyway, as I presume it just restores the project schedule.

I know the old project site's (with all of the risks/issues) GUID and the current (without any risks/issues), is there a way to restore all of the list items' connection to the new project site through SQL Server?  I'm not certain all of the tables to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot get it from recycle bin then only option is youhave to restor it from backups. If you have the SQL Backup of your content DB then peform the following steps.

1. Restore backup of content database in SQL server
2. Launch Central Admin and Navigate to >> Backup and Restore >> Recover data from unattached content database.
3. Enter restored database name and select option export site or list
4. Export your desired site
5. Restore exported site using Import-spweb on the desired location.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much.  Fortunately, our company takes database backups once a day and holds them for 30 days.  Question - will this restore only the project site, or will it also restore all of the risks/issues and lists associated with that project site as well?

Comment: once you export the project subsite it will restore everything

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would work but have you checked you recycle bin? There's 3 different ones in sharepoint!

Open any site

Click on “Settings” icon in the top right side of the site

Select “Site Contents”

Select Recycle Bin on the right

It will take you to this page.

http://myhost.com/sites/MyTestSite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx

This is the 1st Stage “Recycle Bin”

When you delete from the 1st stage recycle bin, items are transferred to the 2nd Stage recycle bin.

You cannot remove items from 2nd stage Recycle Bin, unless you are a site collection administrator.

2nd Stage “Recycle Bin”

How to access 2nd Stage “Recycle Bin”.

Click on “Settings” icon in the top right side of the site.

Select “Site Settings”

If you’re in a sub site, you may need to navigate to the root of the site collection by clicking “Go to top level site settings” in the “Site Collection Administration” section.

From the “Site Collection Administration” section click “Recycle Bin”. If you remove items from here, then you cannot restore..

If I don't remember correct you have a recycle bin in central administrator ass well!

http://captainofsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/sharepoint-2013-recycle-bin-tricks/

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, I'm not able to find the Project Site in any of these recycle bins. Is it a permanent delete?

Answer (score 0):

kind of late replying to this but you can see the site from get-spdeletedsite, and probably remove-spdeletedsite or restore-spdeletedsite to either permanently remove it or to restore it back.